# Compiler warning from std::chrono but is not being used

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-warnings

NOTE: This bug only occurs with x64 projects in both release and debug modes.

Odd warnings involving `std::chrono` appear on this piece of code using VC2019 at warning level 3. This is a stripped down piece of code that processes command line flags. I've removed most of the guts that aren't relevant to the problem.

```
#if 1   // enable bug
#include <chrono>   // excluding this also eliminates chrono warnings
using CorrectedIntType=int;
#else
using CorrectedIntType=size_t;
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

namespace {
    void fixup(const std::string& argcmd, std::string& arg) { arg = argcmd; }

    template<class T>
    void procVal(std::vector<std::string>& arglist, CorrectedIntType idx, T& arg)
    {
        fixup(arglist[idx], arg);
        arglist.erase(arglist.begin() + idx);
    }

    template<class T, class ...TA>
    void procVal(std::vector<std::string>& arglist, CorrectedIntType idx, T& arg, TA&...argv)
    {
        procVal(arglist, idx, arg);
        procVal(arglist, idx, argv...);
    }

    template<class T, class ...TA>
    bool procFlag(const char* pc, std::vector<std::string>& arglist, T& arg1, TA&...argv)
    {
        std::string flag(pc);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arglist.size(); i++)
        {
            if (arglist[i] == flag)
            {
                arglist.erase(arglist.begin() + i);
                procVal(arglist, i, arg1);      // process one argument after flag
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    string outfile;
    vector<string> test = { "test" };
    procFlag("-o", test, outfile);      // assigns test[0] to outfile and removes it
    std::cout << outfile << '\n';
}
```

Warnings:

```
1>Source.cpp
1>C:\Users\mgray\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CommandLineCPP\stackoverflow\Source.cpp(35,1): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'CorrectedIntType', possible loss of data
1>C:\Users\mgray\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CommandLineCPP\stackoverflow\Source.cpp(54): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool `anonymous-namespace'::procFlag<std::string,>(const char *,std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>> &,T &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=std::string
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\chrono(632): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1,1>>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\chrono(178): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::duration<__int64,std::nano>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\chrono(610): message : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::nanoseconds>' being compiled
```

While the code works, even with the `int -<> size_t` conversion issue which is a legitimate warning, all warnings go away when the macro at the top is set to 0. So somehow the size difference between size_t and int triggers chrono messages. It concerns me that the `chrono` warnings exist since it isn't involved. Is this a bug in VS2019? Any ideas as to why the `chrono` warning references are occurring?

Comment: Are you, perchance, using a Windows SDK from an older version of VS? If so, the STL headers there may not be compatible with the "strictness" and language standard settings for your VS2019 project.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm using the latest SDK and created a new solution to test out the snippet in case there was some setting I had made. But I'll check it in a new install on a different machine. BTW, same errors in a x64 and x86 compile.

Comment: I ran your code in my VS2019 at W3 with conformance mode on in debug mode x86 and I get no warnings at all.  If you run this exact example, do you get the warning?  I ask because the compiler warnings for `Source.cpp` don't match what you have.  They refer to lines in the 1300's and that doesn't match up.

Comment: The initial *real* warning is about precision loss for conversion from size_t to int. Those *messages* might just be follow ups where this former issue might play a role (*'see reference'*). Using size_t as corrected type, too, with chrono included might eliminate the chrono related messages as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I just ran the code on a different machine where the VC2019 was a fresh install and it also shows no errors. I checked and `/permissive-` is set for conformance and they have the same include search paths and other compiler settings. However the machine it's showing up on has been upgraded sequentially from earlier versions so perhaps something wasn't upgraded properly. I'll do a deep dive tomorrow. Both were set for C++17  The lines are apparently in `chrono`

Comment: @doug Your warnbing says `Source.cpp(1343,1): warning C4267:` which means the problem is from line 1343.  There is no line 1343 so the code show cant be the code that is in this post.

Comment: @Aconcagua. The errors go away when size_t is used instead of int regardless of whether chrono is included. However, if chrono is included then the errors occur when int is used. Interestingly, no errors occur with a fresh install on another computer. Strange.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica. You're right. I initially paired the code down by commenting out lots of stuff. The code I pasted was from the bottom of that. I'll remove the commented top and edit the question.

Comment: Okay.  Just trying to make sure the code that is the issue is what is shown.  Pretty sure it was but you wouldn't be the first person that was looking at the wrong code if it wasn't

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica Just re-ran it removing the commented out stuff and edited the question. Thanks for noticing that!

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I've found a way to easily replicate the problem with a current VS2019. Create a console app. Paste in the problem code. Compile. No problem. Now delete the hidden ".vs" directory in the solution folder and reload the program. The bug occurs.  VS2019 recreates the ".vs" folder but with a different structure ???  And, of course, GIT doesn't back up the ".vs" folder. My concern is where else this may become a problem rather than an annoyance or what options enable this peculiar behavior.

Comment: I can reproduce the warning even without `#include <chrono>`.  The problem is the truncation from `size_t` to `int`. `chrono` is a red herring. Indeed, I get [no warnings about `chrono` at all](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/QNVmFt).

Comment: @RaymondChen Yeah, looks like a wild goose chase. Turns out the chrono references are spurious. No idea what causes them since chrono is not involved in the C4267 warning or anywhere else in the code. When I deleted the .vs folder the solution reverted to x86 from x64 dropping C4267 but I didn't notice the reversion, Duh. Still am concerned as to why the chrono messages are getting output but it hopefully isn't a sign of some other issue. I'm fine with warnings that I understand.

Comment: The warning is still reproducible in the latest MSVC and without <chrono>, demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1WYMa7Tjq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a valid warning and it is not related to `<chrono>` but to your own code and `CorrectedIntType` type. Here is a simplified code without `<chrono>`: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qf9v8TEh7

In the definition of `procVal`, the second parameter is `CorrectedIntType`:

```
void procVal(std::vector<std::string>& arglist, CorrectedIntType idx, T& arg)
```

but it is called from `procFlag` with `size_t` value:

```
bool procFlag(const char* pc, std::vector<std::string>& arglist, T& arg1)
    ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arglist.size(); i++)
    ...
            procVal(arglist, i, arg1);
```

So one can fix the warning by changing `i` type to `CorrectedIntType` as well.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting how it shows up. Template error obfuscation madness.